# What is the latest version of GUI: 0.12.2.0?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, lithium-luna

On www.getmonero.org it says that the latest version to download is Lithium Luna 0.12.2.0, but when I download the zip file, it says the zip file name is 0.12.0.0.    I'm having trouble when sending funds, as it hangs forever and then often says that daemon isn't connected.  I thought the new version may fix this, but don't see it posted for download.

Answer (score 3):

[This reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/8puzqr/) says it all: Official GUI build is still v0.12.0.0. [The one on getmonero.org](https://getmonero.org/downloads/#linux) claims to be 0.12.2.0 but actually is still the old version. CLI build is up to date.

If you need latest GUI, build from source yourself. If you just need the daemon/`monero-wallet-cli`, official CLI build is (correctly) up to date.